# How to disable spell checking in Android Studio Navigation Bar and editor window tabs

Tags: android-studio

[image: Spell checking hints in Android Studio Navigation Bar]

I globally disabled spell checking in Settings -> Editor -> Inspections (using Android Studio 4.0.1 for Mac) but the navigation bar and editor window tabs still show spell checking underlines. How do I get rid of this "feature"?

Comment: I assume you tried restarting your IDE? (Maybe try `Invalidate Caches/Restart`)

Comment: Yes I did, the red lines keep coming back.